# Are laws of thoughts axioms or inference rules in logical systems?

Tags: logic, philosophy

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_thought says

> The laws of thought are fundamental axiomatic rules upon which rational discourse itself is often considered to be based.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_thought#The_three_traditional_laws lists three and represent them in formal logic:

> Three traditional laws: identity, non-contradiction, excluded middle
>
> - The law of identity: For all a: a = a.
> - The law of non-contradiction: ¬(A∧¬A).
> - The law of excluded middle:  A∨¬A.

Are laws of thoughts tautologies?

Are laws of thoughts axioms, theorems, or inference rules in logical systems? If not, what are they in logical systems?

Are tautologies  axioms, theorems, or inference rules in logical systems? If not, what are they in logical systems?

Some of the laws of thoughts are used for defining the class of classical logics. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_logic#Characteristics. Does this link define the class of classical logics by having the laws of thoughts as their axioms, theorems,  or as something else?

> Each logical system in the class of classical logics shares characteristic properties:[3]
>
> - Law of excluded middle and double negation elimination
> - Law of noncontradiction, and the principle of explosion
> - Monotonicity of entailment and idempotency of entailment
> - Commutativity of conjunction
> - De Morgan duality: every logical operator is dual to another

Thanks.

Comment: Certainly formal logic represents rules of inference as a fundamental aspect of such systems.  There is a threshold of reasoning which is needed to check that these formal procedures are being followed.  For example, in a typical rule of inference (modus ponens) one needs to check the ordering of expressions in a list that makes up a "proof".  Does verifying that order need yet another formal procedure?  Also checking that an expression is valid in the syntax of a formal language involves some reasoning, perhaps at the level of counting.  Formal logic is in this sense built on informal logic.

Comment: I am not sure how informal vs formal logic is involved in my questions. I am only thinking of formal logic.  Do you think of laws of thoughts  as informal? The link also represents laws of thoughts in symbols. Do you mean laws of thoughts are inference rules?

Comment: Some of the terms you use have precise meanings in the context of formal logic.  "Laws of thought" is not such a term, but perhaps some of the things you ask can be addressed by extension of the formal logic context.  My Comment was intended, not to answer your Question, but to request clarification of what kind of reasoned mathematical argument could possibly address it.  Are there kinds of reasoning that stand "outside" of formal logic?  Yes, that's my point.  Perhaps you can clarify the definition of "laws of thought" (also G. Boole's title of his classic book).

Comment: The idea of laws of thoughts might have come from informal logic, but I quoted from the link which represents laws of thoughts in symbols in formal logic.

Comment: The answer will heavily depend on the exact formulation of formal logic that you're using.  For example, natural deduction tends to make everything into an inference rule, whereas Hilbert style proof systems go more for the route of using modus ponens as the only inference rule and casting other principles as logical axioms.

Comment: @DanielSchepler What do the inference rules look like when they are made from the  laws: identity, non-contradiction, excluded middle ?

Comment: Well, the "law of identity" would be a rule that in any context $\Gamma$ and for any term $\tau$, $\Gamma \vdash \tau = \tau$.  The other "laws" are usually derived from other principles in a natural deduction system.  For example, some steps in proving the law of non-contradiction would involve using the ${\land}E$ inference rule that says: if $\Gamma \vdash p \wedge q$ then you can conclude $\Gamma \vdash p$ or you can also conclude $\Gamma \vdash q$ where $p$ and $q$ are proposition formulas.  ...

Comment: Along with the inference rule ${\lnot}I$ which says: if $\Gamma \cup \{ p \} \vdash \bot$ (here $\bot$ represents the false proposition), then $\Gamma \vdash \lnot p$.  In other words, if after adding an assumption of $p$ to the current context you can derive a contradiction, then in the original context without $p$ added, you can conclude $\lnot p$.

Comment: As well as the rule ${\lnot} E$ which says: if $\Gamma \vdash p$ and $\Gamma \vdash \lnot p$ as well for some propositional formula $p$, then $\Gamma \vdash \bot$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Thanks. Some of the laws of thoughts are used for defining the class of classical logics. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_logic#Characteristics. Does this link define the class of classical logics by having the laws of thoughts as their axioms  or as something else?

Comment: That link appears to be more focused on *properties* which a logic can have, e.g. which statements it proves in some way, than on whether those properties happen to be direct axioms or inference rules of the logic or whether they need to be derived as theorems (or metatheorems).

Comment: @DanielSchepler What is "properties which a logic can have, e.g. which statements it proves in some way"?

Comment: Some are *axioms* (e.g. $a=a$), some are "theorems", i.e. derived from axioms. In both cases, they are "tautologies", i.e. *valid* formulas (true in every domain of discourse).